Kotlin WebView is unable to ask user for geolocation permissions
I'm unable to watch user's geolocation in WebView launched by Kotlin code.
From the html page we need to watch the user's geolocation (
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {...}


).
For a standalone browser, this pops up the permission dialog. For a WebView, no permission dialog is displayed and no geolocation is reported. I've tried with the manifest included
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

and the following WebView
            WebView(context).apply {
                settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                settings.cacheMode = android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
                settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true
                settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
                settings.databaseEnabled = true
                settings.domStorageEnabled = true
                settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {

                    override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                        super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
                        component.onPageProgressChanged(newProgress)
                    }

                    override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
                        origin: String?,
                        callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback?
                    ) {
                        super.onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(origin, callback)
                        callback?.invoke(origin, true, true);
                    }

                    override fun onGeolocationPermissionsHidePrompt() {
                        super.onGeolocationPermissionsHidePrompt()
                    }
                }

